# google oauth2 authentication error

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-authentication

I am trying to build an android app to insert and retrieve events from google calendar using Google calendar API.

```
`GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());`
```

whenever I try to access the API it gives me the error UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE.
I have followed the steps on calendar API Page to register API key on developer console

Comment: this might be help http://stackoverflow.com/a/41000914/3758024

Comment: Thanks @gopal_patil, i'll try that out

Comment: Thank You @gopal_patil it worked

Comment: glad to hear that Happy coding (Y).